# Can I type in inverse case, lIKE tHIS, with caps lock on?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, keyboard, caps-lock

Every so often, I have to type some text consisting mostly of uppercase letters, but with an occasional lowercase letter—essentially, sentence case, but inverted. On Windows, I would simply have caps lock on the entire time, and pressing Shift would give me a lowercase letter. On OS X, however, if caps lock is on, I only get uppercase letters, whether Shift is pressed or not.

So, I can either hold down Shift the entire time I'm typing, letting go of it briefly to type a lowercase letter, or press Caps Lock twice for each lowercase letter I type. Neither works as well as what Windows does.

Is there a way to get Caps Lock to behave as it does on Windows, where pressing Shift while caps lock is on produces lowercase letters?

I am running 10.6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### See Update below...

It seems (only) the input source "French - Numerical" will behave like Window Caps Lock (with iNVERSE sHIFT):

[image: keyboard layout French - Numerical]

Found that info [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/36625/14994).

But note that this will come with a rather unusual keyboard layout (at least for me).

[image: keyboard layout French - Numerical1]

[image: keyboard layout French - Numerical2]

### Update: Using [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=ukelele) this can be applied to all keyboard layouts:

Thanks [Daniel](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9388/daniel) for pointing the right direction.

Open Ukelele and save your (current) layout to a file (e.g. by "New from current input source" and "Save"):

[image: New from current input source]

Open the `.xml` file in a text editor and find the `mapIndex` that you want to use for the combination <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⇪</kbd> (shift + caps-lock). For German I used `mapIndex="0"`. Insert this line:

```
<modifier keys="shift caps"/>
```

Find all other occurrences of this combination and comment them out (or delete the lines). Again for German it's:

```
<keyMapSelect mapIndex="1">
<modifier keys="anyShift"/>
<modifier keys="shift rightShift? caps? rightOption? rightControl"/>
<modifier keys="shift rightShift? caps? rightOption rightControl?"/>
<!--<modifier keys="shift rightShift? caps rightOption? rightControl?"/> -->
    </keyMapSelect>
```

[image: shift caps]

Re-open the modified file with Ukelele.

Here is a comparison of the "German" layout before and after the modification:

[image: layout 1]

[image: layout 2]

Follow the instructions in Ukelele to create a new input source (Name, ID, installation).

I didn't test the modified file, should work though.

Comment: Which suggests that it's a feature that could be added to other layouts as well. I'm sure it can be done in Ukelele, but I haven't learned how yet.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel for that comment - I figured it out. I'll add the procedure to my answer.

Comment: This, however, will prevent you from using the !@#$%^&*() keys (Shifted top row number keys). To use those, I created [a custom layout which replicates exactly the "PC" behaviour on OS X](https://gist.github.com/2946420). Do note that this is for the US layout only, if you use another you'll have to do it yourself :)

Answer (score -1):

From what I have experienced, it cannot be done in OS X. None of the keyboard reconfiguration utilities I have tried seem to be able to do it either. Sorry. :(

Answer (score -2):

Thank you [Félix Saparelli](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/24123/f%C3%A9lix-saparelli)! Your [custom layout](https://gist.github.com/passcod/2946420) works beautifully for me on macOS Big Sur 11.2.2. I followed the instructions [here](http://www.languagegeek.com/keyboard_general/mac_installation1.html) to install by saving file.xml as "/Library/Keyboard Layouts/us_en_caps_lock_fix.keylayout", rebooting, and selecting the new Input Source. This layout has "shift inverts case" behaviour, symbols are produced when shifted, and numbers are produced when not shifted.