# How does one type an "É" (capital e acute) in the French keyboard layout in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard, firefox, internationalization

I've searched the web for a method to type an "**É**" character with a french keyboard layout in firefox.

It appears I'm supposed to type <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, and then <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to achieve this, but as soon as I press <kbd>⌥</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd> simultaneously, an

## ê

character appears. Why, and what should I try instead?

I'm using Lion.

Comment: Dead simple? How are you even supposed to think that hitting caps lock would make any sense ever?

Comment: @Debilski: dead simple to use != dead simple to discover. But it is a really normal behavior for a key named "capitals lock"

Comment: Well, you’re probably correct. It does make sense in a way. I think I must have never thought about the real meaning of the word.

Comment: I didn't either until I first saw this behavior on linux. Because I'm not an native english speaker. Then I re-analyzed what `Caps Lock` means, and what `Shift` means.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

French layout?

1. Press caps lock <kbd>⇪</kbd>.
2. Press the <kbd>é</kbd> key (that's the <kbd>2</kbd> on a QWERTY).
3. Press caps lock <kbd>⇪</kbd> again.

---

But you need to make sure you're using the *French* layout, and not *French - numeric* (“Français - numérique”, French flag with “123” beneath it).

[image: French keyboard layouts in Mac OS X]

Otherwise, you're explicitly asking the system to use the caps lock key as a shift lock for the numbers bar on the top of the keyboard!

Comment: As I already said, this gives a 2, which is also the stupid behavior of Microsoft Windows. This works on Linux. Maybe this is configurable... if yes please tell me how.

Comment: That's because you're using the “Français - numérique” layout (French flag with “123” beneath it) instead of the “Français” layout (French flag only), aren't you?

Comment: I think the numeric version is the one which emulates the ancient French typewriter layout. The one which did not have any capital accented letters at all.

Comment: To do it more smoothly you can keep caps lock pressed.

Answer (score 7):

To type this character, type <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, then <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>. "**É**" is the character I get.

In Lion, I understand one can hold down the key, a la iOS, and get a list of possible characters with accents for many of the keys:

[image]

Comment: Yes, in Lion you hold Shift+E in that case.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @greg0ire You should only type and hold Shift+E. Does this not work?

Comment: Holding Shift+E displays EEEEEEEEEE. Testing in firefox.

Comment: Try textedit, Chrome. Firefox might not support this (already).

Comment: Works in textedit. +1

Comment: Thanks for the nice workaround, I edited my question to specify I want a solution for firefox. I won't accept your solution in this state, but you still get my upvote. My main question remains: why do I get this `ê` character?

Comment: @greg0ire I suspect the instruction to use option-E is based on a US keyboard layout, since this is indeed how you would get the character on a US keyboard.

Comment: You're right, since there is no <kbd>é</kbd> key on a US keyboard, an alternative method was necessary to write internationally-used french expressions inside american texts.

Answer (score 7):

The standard dead-key combo for a French layout is <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>&</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.

Comment: Oh this is sooooo handy! 5 keystrokes! What a nice OS! Anyway, thank you very much for this answer. Upvoted, accepted!

Comment: @greg0ire Haha! That really is a lot of effort needed for such a letter. Maybe you should create a new question and ask if you can assign a shortcut for those five keystrokes?

Comment: @gentmatt: Thank god, there's a reasonable, Linux-like solution! I don't know why this computer was configured that way. It's brand new, so it must be the default... strange.

Comment: I think the reason it is so difficult is the idea some French language experts have that you don't need to ever show accent marks on capital letters.  Seems totally crazy to me when it comes to digital text.

Comment: @TomGewecke but see http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#5_strong-em-accentuation-des-majuscules-em-strong for a rather authoritative counterargument.

Comment: @greg0ire That is indeed an obnoxious set of keystrokes, but it's a function of the keyboard layout, not the OS in general. It's 3 keystrokes in my keyboard layout.

Answer (score 2):

For those who have a Swiss-French layout here are the key combinations to make `É`:

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.

In Swiss-French layout, the symbol <kbd>`</kbd> is the grave accent and can be accessed by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd> and the acute accent <kbd>´</kbd> is accessed by the other combination: <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>^</kbd>.

Only the grave accent is printed on the top of the <kbd>^</kbd> key.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Edit` menu and press `Special Character` (<kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and from opening window go to Latin tab and find `É`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know about this method, but I'm searching for something more simple. On linux, I just type <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, then <kbd>é</kbd>, and I'm done. On Mac OS, this gives me a 2 (on windows too).

Comment: I suggest this solution because I can type É when I first press option+e then shift+e, I must mention that I have OS X lion.

Comment: I'm using OS X lion, and my main problem is to know why you can do this and I can't.

Answer (score 1):

in Lion just hold <kbd>e</kbd> or if you need in uppercase hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> and you will have an option pop up

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I have tested this in firefox search box, and in gmail's search box.

Comment: Lion’s keyboard now brings up a palette that lets you choose an accented or alternate character. 
`defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool (true|false)`
Hit Return, log out and back into your account. Have also tested this in Chrome and it works for me. Can you confirm if it works outside Firefox?

Comment: Could you please edit your answer or your comment and use backticks to show the command line? I'm having trouble seeing where it starts... Does it really start with `-g` ?!?

Comment: Also forgot to mention that it only works for the default English keyboard layout (not all apps support this and hence may not be system wide)

Comment: My keyboard layout is french, so this command isn't worth trying, is it?

Comment: Anyway, I get the palette (the thing Smitty is describing) in textedit, so I guess this boolean is already set to true.

Comment: Note for others who were screwing it up like me -- let go of Shift before pressing 2 to select the option from the pop-up, otherwise a `@` is inserted.

Answer (score -2):

In French grammar, the rules are that there are no accents on upper case letters. This error was introduced with Microsoft word which enforced accenting upper case letters and was fixed since then. The rules never changed and it is still grammatically wrong to put an accent on an upper case letter in French.

Comment: So what about this:  http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#5_strong-em-accentuation-des-majuscules-em-strong

Comment: @Aude Robinson : Any source to back up this ? I don't believe you at all.

Comment: @greg0ire Indeed, I think it is nonsense.  My copy of Grevisse, a 1000+ page French grammar, is full of accented capitals.  I believe the Imprimerie Nationale requires accented capitals.

Comment: @Aude Robinson: I think you should delete your answer.

Comment: It certainly doesn't answer the question at all whether or not it is true.

Comment: @TomGewecke your link is dead, here is the updated one: http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#5_strong-em-accentuation-des-majuscules-em-strong. Yes the académie said the uppercase must always be accented then this answer is just wrong (and does not answer the OP question).